# I have to reduce my question to a homogeneous ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1-x-y+1}{y-x-5}$$

I've taken the substitutions $x=X+h$ and $y=Y+k$, but my answers appear to be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the question correctly? The string `1 - x - y + 1` looks odd. Why isn't it just `2 - x - y`?

Answer (score 0):

let
$$x=X+k_1$$
$$y=Y+k_2$$
to cancel the constants $2$ and $-5$, it should be

$$k_1+k_2=-2\tag1$$
$$k_2-k_1=5\tag2$$
so
$$k_1=-\frac{3}{2}$$
$$k_2=\frac{7}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $$x=-1.5+u\\ y=3.5+v\\ \frac { dv }{ du } =\frac { -u-v }{ v-u } $$